# Adding FeatureLayer to map using ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

How do I add an existing layer to my map using ArcGIS Pro SDK?

I saw several examples where the layer is added while being created (for example

```
LayerFactory.Instance.CreateFeatureLayer(new Uri(strUri), map);
```

), however, how this is being done for, let's say, FeatureLayer from geodatabase?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of examples for how to do this in the help wiki. 
If you are trying to add a layer from a geodatabase then you would first create an object that references the gdb and then open the feature class. 
See here:
[ProConcepts Geodatabase](https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-Geodatabase#mygeodatabase)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, so if anyone comes into this situation this is it:

```
LayerFactory.Instance.CopyLayer(sourceLayer, map);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a feature class in a geodatabase then use the below, where fc is a FeatureClass object:

```
var layerParams = new FeatureLayerCreationParams(fc);
var layer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer<FeatureLayer>(layerParams, MapView.Active.Map);
```